# pyspark dictionary of each elements

Tags: pyspark

I am a newbie in pyspark
I have a data like table below. I want each elemnt in the 'Brand' to be my keys and 'cloths' to be my value. How can I do it in pyspark?

```
cloths |Brand
-------------
shirt  |[x,y]
       |
pants  |[x,y,z,hi]
```

Output wanted:

```
x:shirt

y:shirt

x:pants

y:pants

z:pants

hi:pants
```

Thanks for your help

Comment: Pyspark works with dataframe. Therefore, when you talk about key/value, it doesn't make much sens. Do you want 2 columns, one key, one value ? or do you want a map column ?

Comment: Is this a pyspark dataframe or rdd? I am hoping you need something like `explode` in [pyspark.sql](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.2.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.explode)

Comment: it should be a RDD

Comment: you can convert it in a `dataframe` and use `explode` over the column.

Comment: Thanks! but I should work with RDD

Comment: I want RDDs of type (K, V)

Comment: yes it works Now how can I tranform it to dictionary?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to work with `rdd`, you just need to call [`flatMap()`](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.flatMap). This will allow you to iterate over the `cloths` list to create your desired output, and flatten the results.

If you want each row to be a tuple of `(key, value)`:

```python
rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [tuple([b, row['cloths']]) for b in row['Brand']]).collect()
#[(u'x', u'shirt'),
# (u'y', u'shirt'),
# (u'x', u'pants'),
# (u'y', u'pants'),
# (u'z', u'pants'),
# (u'hi', u'pants')]
```

Or if you wanted each row to be a dictionary:

```python
rdd.flatMap(lambda row: [{b: row['cloths']} for b in row['Brand']]).collect()
#[{u'x': u'shirt'},
# {u'y': u'shirt'},
# {u'x': u'pants'},
# {u'y': u'pants'},
# {u'z': u'pants'},
# {u'hi': u'pants'}]
```